# Visualization for a Query builder using items from a Tree like structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a dynamic query based on the user selections from the items that are arranged in a tree like structure. Once the user selects an item from the tree, I should display the conditions (like equals, not equals, wild card match etc) and text field to enter a value. Users will be able to select more than one item from the tree and provide values. Items in the tree are grouped by their type (or parent). After all the selections, I compose a query (sql like) form the user input. I would like to do this using Javscript and back end is supported by java code. In my research I found out that there are many JQuery plugins to display the tree like structure. I want to take the community input on building other types of visualization for this. Is there any other better way to graphically display this to the user instead of a Tree like structure?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide code or an example?

Comment: I don't have the code yet. This question is mainly about the design choice. I just added a conceptual image.